# i can't retrieve sql rows in java where one of the rows is NULL

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

i'm building my JTable in a java application so that i can query my sql database according to different criteria i will select on several comboboxes. This is my entire database viewed from PHPMyAdmin,

http://s21.postimg.org/tcnsklzk7/base_de_datos.png

i'm trying to print it in my JTable but it only works when there's no null values in any of the rows printed like in the rows of Agapito Noguera, but if i'm showing results that include NULL like in Yasuri Gonzales it doesn't show anything in the JTable it only says null in the output screen like this

http://s15.postimg.org/nxsrjawgr/null_programa.png

this is the code that handles the output of the rows:

```
        String query="SELECT `nombre solicitante`,`apellido solicitante`,`nombre status`,`nombre canal`,"+
            "`nombre municipio`,`gmvv`,`0800mihogar`,`nombre situacion` FROM `solicitante` LEFT OUTER JOIN"+
            " `solicitud` ON `solicitante`.`cedula solicitante`=`solicitud`.`cedula solicitante` "+
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN `canal` ON `solicitud`.`id canal`=`canal`.`id canal` LEFT OUTER JOIN `status` "+
            "ON `solicitud`.`id status`=`status`.`id status` LEFT OUTER JOIN `municipio` ON "+
            "`solicitud`.`id municipio`=`municipio`.`id municipio`    LEFT OUTER JOIN `situacion solicitante`"+
            " ON `solicitud`.`id solicitud`=`situacion solicitante`.`id solicitud` LEFT JOIN `situacion` ON"+
            " `situacion solicitante`.`id situacion`=`situacion`.`id situacion` "
            + "WHERE `solicitante`.`nombre solicitante`='yndra' AND `situacion`.`id situacion`=1 "
            + "ORDER BY `nombre solicitante`,`apellido solicitante`";
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query);

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnas = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<Object[]> data=new ArrayList<>();
    while(rs.next()){
        Object[] rows=new Object[columnas];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnas;i++) {
            rows[i]=rs.getObject(i+1).toString();
        }
        data.add(rows);
    } 
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
        dtm.addRow(data.get(i));
    }
```

how can i print the NULL fields in my JTable?

Comment: I guess the problem is in this secction: rows[i]=rs.getObject(i+1).toString() try String.valueOf(rs.getObject(i+1))

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't show the null error anymore but it still doesn't output the rows in the jatable. also check the images i put on my message to see if it helps you understand

Comment: try adding to the query for columns that return null and see if that helps http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php

Comment: ok i read your link and tried now wraping my columns in an IFNULL() but now it's printing the 11 rows in blank